# Cropping NVARCHAR(MAX) before submitting to database - what length?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, nvarchar

I have a SQL row with type

```
summary NVARCHAR(4000) NULL
```

and before I add any data to the table I check it in code and fix it if the user has entered a string that is too long for the database using this code

```
if (instanceToCrop.Description != null && instanceToCrop.Description.Length > 4000) instanceToCrop.Description = instanceToCrop.Description.Substring(0, 4000);
```

If I change my table thus

```
ALTER TABLE Timeline
ALTER COLUMN summary NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

what constant should I use in place of 4000 to keep the submitted string below the length that the SQL server would reject?

Comment: You should not allow the user to enter that many characters from the UI side rather then checking from the database side.  If you are using .net there is a maxlength property for a textbox.

Comment: JonH, agreed. The UI check is less than this, but I'm being cautious and including a check in the code surrounding the database too.
Joel - interesting, thanks for that

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn since it's Unicode that would represent the number of bytes but not the number of characters, since each character requires two bytes, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max number of characters you can store in an NVARCHAR(MAX) is 1,073,741,823 or very close to that. If your users can enter that amount of text in your textbox, there's probably something not optimal going on ... are they pasting The Bible or the transcript for all of the Lord of the Rings movies?

I think you can set a much more practical limit, but we can't really tell you what that should be... 50,000 characters? 100,000 characters? Something less than 64KB for network / packet reasons? Don't know, that seems to be a business decision, not a technical one.

Comment: Funny you should say that - the King James Version is one of the texts I've been using as an archetypal long text!

Comment: One thing that is confusing me is the documented 4000 max for NVARCHAR [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx): "n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000". If, for business reasons, I need the maximum length to be 16,000 characters does that mean I have to use NVARCHAR(MAX) in the database anyway?

Comment: @dumbledad the syntax diagram states that you can use `n | max` - `|` = `or`. When you use a numeric value (`n`) it must be between 1 and 4000. If you need more than 4000 characters, you use `max` instead of a numeric value, which allows for 2GB of data (a little over 1 billion characters). Personally I think the cutoff between non-max and max should be 900 bytes (450 characters for nvarchar), since that's the limit of using the column as part of an index key. But I realize it is also for page reasons.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I understand the syntax diagram but the huge jump between 4,000 and over 1 billion didn't make sense to me. From your comment it sounds like there are technical page reasons.

Comment: Right, without getting into all of the nuances of how a page works, a page holds ~8k, which allows for one varchar(8000) value fully populated, or one nvarchar(4000) value fully populated - again, not precisely, but those are the nice round numbers (it would be even more confusing if the limits were, say, 8040 / 4020).